# What's the best way to sum two array in place in Scala?

Tags: scala

`(a,b).zipped.map(_+_)` will create a new Array.
However, I want to change value in "a" in-place, for-cycle will be ok, but not clear

Comment: Best by what criterion?

Comment: Changing anything in place in scala is not "best" by any criteria to begin with.

Comment: @Dima, thank you , I guess you mean "val is better than var", can you explain more？

Comment: @Fan no. `val` _is_ better than `var`, but that's not what I meant. I meant don't change arrays (or anything else) in place.

Comment: @Dima,do you mean "for (i <- 0 until a.length) { a(i) = a(i) + b(i) }" is not good, why?

Comment: Yeah, that's what i mean.

Comment: @Dima, I don't understand why, can you explain more? Thank you.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133330/whats-wrong-with-mutability-and-can-it-be-desirable

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like the below

```
for (i <- 0 until a.length) { a(i) = a(i) + b(i) }
```

Comment: Or `a.indices.foreach(x => a(x) += b(x))`, but `b` can't be smaller than `a`. That's the advantage of `zip`.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know if there is some function like `BLAS.axpy(a:Double, x:Vector, y:Vector) // y += a*x`